# Use of meta class in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Can someone please explain why is meta class used in the following example.

Ex:

```
Class Employee (models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(name)
    Gender = models.IntegerField()


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["Gender"]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because author/programmer wants to sort results by value of Gender field.

Answer (score 26):

Django models use the `Meta` class to contain extra information about the model that would not necessarily be appropriate to contain within the model class itself. Note that this is *not* the same as Python's `metaclass`; that is a completely different topic.

In this case it ordering or sorting the queries to this model by field "Gender"

Answer (score 3):

In this case it defines the default field for ordering if you don't provide `ORDER_BY` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in Django Documentation for Models

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/
```

Give your model metadata by using an inner class Meta, like:

```
Class Employee (models.Model):
    ....

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["attribute-X"]
```

Another useful option can be used in class Meta is verbose_name.